# TensorFlow memory management

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a network as follows

```
def _create_network(self, scope='network'):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope):
        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, *self.img_shape, self.hist_len], dtype=tf.float32)
        self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=16,
                                  kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME')
        self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                                  kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME')
        self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_2), 256, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
        self.outputs = slim.fully_connected(self.fc, self.env.action_space.n, activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax)
        # get all the weights
        self._weights = tf.trainable_variables()
```

And I want to use all the weights to train my model, but here, my model is a gradient-free model, so I only need to assign the value of weights

I got the values by

```
self._real_weights = self._sess.run(self._weights)
```

And then use these values to train my model and update the values of weights in the graph

```
for i in range(n_iters):
    # do something arithmetic operation with self._real_weights
    # without any tensors in the graph
    self._sess.run([tf_var.assign(real_var) for tf_var, real_var in zip(self._weights, self._real_weights)])
    gc.collect()
```

But, what made me feel confused is the memory of the machine increased steadily until all the memory were taken up.

Is there something wrong with my code?